# Difference between + and += on Java Strings

Tags: java, string, memory, heap-memory, string-pool

I would like to understand how memory is allocated when we use + and += on Strings in Java.
I know that String literals are stored in the String Constant Pool and in Case #1, both s1 and s2 reference the same memory in String Constant Pool.

In Case #2, eventhough I use a + operator, it still references the same object in String Constant Pool

What I find interesting is Case #3. How and where is memory allocated in this case? How is it different from Case #2

```
//Case #1
String s1 = "Hello Java";
String s2 = "Hello Java";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true

//Case #2
s1 = "Hello" + " Java";
s2 = "Hello Java";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true

s1 = "Hello";
s1 += " Java";
s2 = "Hello Java";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); //false
```

Comment: Use `equals()` for string comparison

Comment: @B001ᛦ: I think it's the OP's *intent* to compare object identity sameness, rather than string equality.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't actually a difference between `+` and `+=`; you'd get the same behavior as Case #3 if you wrote:

```
s1 = "Hello";
s1 = s1 + " Java";
s2 = "Hello Java";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); //false
```

The reason for the behavior you see in Case #2 is that `"Hello" + " Java"` is a *constant expression* [[JLS8 §15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)], so it can actually be handled at compile-time exactly as if it were `"Hello Java"`, and is required to be interned just as `"Hello Java"` is.

When you break it up into separate statements, that's no longer the case, so you get a newly created string [[JLS8 §15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)].